# Formato de data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Preciso formatar data para apresentar na grid, mas não sei a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
$scope.formato[x].dataFormatada = formatDate($scope.consultas[x].data);

function formatDate(date){
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year =  date.getFullYear();

    date = day + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    return date;
}
```

No HTML que monta a grid, eu tenho uma tag tg com ng-repeat para pegar os dados e coloco dentro da tag td:

```
<td>{{consulta.dataFormatada}}</td>
```

E tenho outra dúvida também... como faço para não enviar esse $scope.consulta.dataFormatada em uma requisição? Utilizei o $delete, mas dai os dados somem da grid.

Comment: Recomendo usar JQuery Mask, traz tudo certinho pra ti os campos, tenta ai que facilita muito a vida. Tem pra vários tipos além de data.
Link: http://vinteum.com/jquery-mask-mascaras-para-campos-html-utilizando-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho melhor formata-la no grid (HTML), caso queira algo mais personalizado crie uma diretiva.

```
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}</span>
```

Resultado:

```
2010-10-29 01:40:23 -0200
```

Referência: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date: